# Can't use the right XPath expression for a certain item

Tags: xpath

Tried a lot but can't locate the item from this element using xpath.

```
<div class="info-list-text"><b>Contact</b>: James Crisp</div>
```

I tried this XPath expression, but without luck:

> //div[@class="info-list-text"]/text()

Thanks in advance to take care of this problem.
Btw, I wanna get to "James Crisp"

Comment: Just a terminology point: what you are doing is not parsing. XPath doesn't parse anything, and the only meaningful way to parse "James Crisp" is to split it into a first name and last name.

Comment: Sorry sir  Michael Kay, It was my mistake to erect question like this without proofreading. Gonna rectify it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`normalize-space( translate( //div[@class="info-list-text"]/text() , ':', '' )  )`

It works as follows :

Get the `text` from the `<div>`

Translate `:` into empty string

Then remove any spaces

Comment: Thanks svasa for your kind and accurate answer. I was not around my pc so long. This style is quite foreign to me.

Comment: I tried with xpath tester where both the expressions are correct, I meant your one and my one. However, when i use it in sublime for python coding it doesn't accept ":" this and shows as syntax error. Any workaround?

Comment: The host language might require you to escape the quotes with backslashes?

Comment: @SMth80 Did you use single quote or double quote ? if you do , can you try escaping quotes , you can follow a link given [here](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html)